# Issue about android Interface Callback

Tags: android, interface, callback

At first I want to say that I'm not expert in Android Development also in English.

I have three classes

- MainActivity.java
- MainLayout.java
- SubLayout.java

The Main Activity override `onBackPressed()` function. I need to run a function from both of the Layout classes when back button is pressed in `Activity` class. The layouts are included into the content view of the Activity. The functions are separated class based. So every layout class has there own function to call on back button is pressed. So, I cannot include the function in `onBackPressed()` of Activity.

How can I make a callback for this purpose?
I need to get a signal on each Layout Classes when back button is pressed in Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your question clearly but I think EventBus library may help you in callbacks situations

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus , 
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: EventBus didn't work for me. But, I've made another listener using EventBus's techniques. Thanks, learnt an awesome thing from EventBus